# Getting multiple objects from AWS S3 stops on 50th file

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a public AWS S3 bucket with 150 text files, each `30kB`. I created simple `test.js` file which downloads those 150 files and displays the information that nth file was successfully downloaded:

```
const { GetObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const { S3Client } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const { range } = require('lodash');

const s3 = new S3Client({
  region: 'eu-central-1',
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: 'XXXXX',
    secretAccessKey: 'XXXXX',
  },
});

const test = async () => {
  let counter = 0;

  await Promise.all(
    range(0, 150).map((i) => {
      const getCommand = new GetObjectCommand({
        Key: `test/testfile${i}.txt`,
        Bucket: 'bucketname',
      });

      return s3.send(getCommand).then(() => {
        counter += 1;
        console.log(counter, 'downloaded');
      });
    })
  );

  console.log('Finish!');
};

test();
```

The problem is that the first `50` files are downloaded and then the program stops (without logging "Finish!"). The same thing happens for 150 larger files: `100kB`, `2MB`, `4MB`. In every scenario some kind of limit is fixed to `50` files.

I tested that this problem doesn't exist when files are 15kB - I got some breaks between every chunk of `50` files, but all the files were downloaded.

**Do you have some ideas how to make it download all the files?**

I tried to find some limits connected with AWS S3 but I found nothing.

I tried playing around with `--max-old-space-size=XXX` but it didn't help. Also it doesn't look like some memory issue, because different file sizes have the same limit of `50` files being downloaded.

I tried adding some `sleep` between e.g. first `0-40` files and next `41-80` files, but it also got stuck on `50th` file.

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the same S3Client for 150 operations. While sharing one S3Client is a good practice to a smaller extent, one S3Client cannot handle so many http connections at once. Please note that **[by default aws-sdk-js is configured to handle only up to 50 sockets](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/649a91dd22044b17dc3719d2d5a79220cdc17f37/lib/http/node.js#L151)**.

I think you can configure S3Client by passing a custom agent with other [http.Agent.maxSockets](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#agentmaxsockets) value, but I don’t think that would be a good idea. Never tried it, but it could look something like this:

```js
const https = require('https');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const agent = new https.Agent({
  maxSockets: 150
});


const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  httpOptions: {
    timeout: 2000,
    agent: agent
  }
});
```

A much better solution would be to create a pool of promises, each of which can download one file at a time, as soon as it finishes it starts the next. [This great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56783618/8007403) seems exactly what you need:

```js
Promise.pool = function pool(funcs, inParallel, progressCallback) {
  const promises = [];
  const results = [];

  function getNext() {
    if (funcs.length) {
      return funcs.pop()()
        .catch(() => {})
        .then((res) => {
          results.push(res);
          if (progressCallback) {
            progressCallback(results);
          }
          return getNext();
        });
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(inParallel, funcs.length); i++) {
    promises.push(getNext());
  }
  return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => results);
};

const inParallel = 25; // or other value less or equal than 50
Promise.pool(funcs, inParallel, someCallback)
  .then(() => console.log("all done!"));
```

Comment: Thanks! Increasing maxSockets worked for me.
The second (better) solution unfortuantely doesn't have any effect on the problem - it still stops on 50th file.

Comment: What effect are you aiming for? SDK will always make connections up to the limit of `maxSockets`, but once those connections are freed, it resumes and proceedes with download. Maybe in your use case you just need a higher `maxSockets` value?

Comment: adding to this, there is an npm package that does the promise.pool. It is @supercharge/promise-pool

Answer (score 1):

Below is a sample configuration example to set `maxSockets` with AWS SDK V3

```
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const { NodeHttpHandler } = require('@smithy/node-http-handler');
const https = require('https');

const agent = new https.Agent({
     maxSockets: 150
});

const client = new S3Client({
     requestHandler: new NodeHttpHandler({
         httpsAgent: agent
    })
});
```

Comment: thank you. didn't expect such a horrible api